# Hosting bot on Openshift using Microsoft bot framework Nodejs SDK with proxy

Tags: node.js, openshift, botframework, chatbot, web-chat

I have a problem when hosting my bot on OpenShift (OpenShift Container Platform) registered with the Bot Channels Registration on Azure. 
I am using the Botbuilder SDK Nodejs, and the Openshift is behind a corporate proxy.

I've tried to set a up a global tunnel to force all HTTP requests to go through the tunnel (see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/399#issuecomment-223256399) and [this one](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/1668)). 
I also have set environments variables on Openshift, but still it doesn't work...

It should be a simple way to set up the proxy with the botbuilder... 
Anyone can help me please ?

Thanks !

Comment: Any error message you got? can you confirm the request has cross the OpenShift and your restify server has recieve the request?

Comment: Are you able to make other https requests through the proxy to OpenShift?  For instance, can you setup a simple node.js website that just serves up a static page and get to that from outside?